# Newly added column is not shown in Azure Storage Explorer for Azure Table view

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I added a new column to Azure Table Storage that has more than 1000 records via a function app and executing queries against it in Azure Storage Explorer showing most recent records. However the new column is not in the grid and is not accessible in the Column Options dialog. Refresh button doesn't help. Is there any way to invalidate some Azure Storage Explorer internal cache for this table to make sure all current columns are displayed?

Comment: Have you tried just doing a direct query for the given entity you just added (via partition key + row key), programmatically? FYI there's no notion of "columns" with Azure Table Storage - every entity may have its own set of properties. So this might be a visualization issue (but no way to know unless you do some more testing, such as a programmatic query).

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes, programmatically I can get the value for this column. I believe it is a visualization issue.

Comment: If you try to disconnect Azure Explorer, login in and out, does it help? Also, what version of Storage Explorer are you using ? There was a recent release that rolled out.